# Prevent .msi file blocking from chrome

Tags: .net, google-chrome, windows-installer, installation

I have a .msi file (setup of application developed in .Net) in my webserver (www.example.com/example.msi), and i want my customers download it from their browser. If they use chrome, the .msi after downloading become blocked.

What is the solution to prevent this blocking? If i use https and distribute the file over secure connection, i ll pass by this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is the MSI digitally signed with a code signing certificate?

Comment: Browsers are getting a little crazy if thats the problem. I shouldn't have to pay an extortion fee to get a cert just to publish a product.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the digitally signed msi. The price list starts from 350$. 
@ChristopherPainter If you distibute a product to low-skilled internet users and their browser deny downling, this is a BIG problem, believe me! 

Is there any way to digital sign MSI without payment?

Comment: Google "code signing on the cheap".  I pay something like $80 a year for my company.  I do it for an open source project that I distribute.